# rolling 28 day total, multiple criteria

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
Date    DistrictNumber StorNumber DailyBudget
1-1-19        7100         5          0.5
1-1-19        7100         6          0.2
1-1-19        7200        21          0.7
```

so on and so fourth. There are over 70 district numbers, and over 1000 store numbers for each date between 1-1=2018 and present. I need a query that will give me a rolling 28 day sum of the "DailyBudget" if the "DistrictNumber" is the same. Also a year over year total for for the same criteria. 
Example of a table would be :

```
District  Rolling4WTotalofDailyBudget Rolling4WLastYearDailyBudget

7100                 139.5                  131.6
7200                 159.5                  190.4
7300                 147.1                  151.9 
7400                 181.6                  132.4
```

```
    select bd.districtnumber,     
    sum(case when date between dateadd(dd,-28,dateadd(dd,-1,cast(getdate() as
 date))) and dateadd(dd,-1,cast(getdate() as date)) then db.DailyBudget else 0
 end) as Rolling4DailyBudget,

    sum(case when date between dateadd(YY,-1,dateadd(dd,-29,cast(getdate() as 
date))) and dateadd(YY,-1, dateadd(dd,-1,cast(getdate() as date))) then 
db.DailyBudget else 0 end) as LYRolling4WDailyBudget

    from Budget bd
    group by bd.districtnumber
    order by bd.districtnumber
```

For some reason I am getting the exact same dailybudget for all districts

Answer (score 0):

> I need a query that will give me a rolling 28 day sum of the "DailyBudget" if the "DistrictNumber" is the same

I think this is what you want:

```
select bd.districtnumber, date,
       sum(sum(db.DailyBudget)) over (partition by bd.districtnumber order by date rows between 28 preceding and 1 preceding) as  Rolling4WeekDailyBudget
from Budget bd
group by bd.districtnumber, date
order by bd.districtnumber, date;
```

Comment: Thank you, this will sum rows but because I have the same date for over 1000 "stores" not sure this will work. I need a rolling 28 day sum of all 'stores' 'dailybudget' when the 'districtnumbers' are the same.